# Process Service Thread

Tags: multithreading, service, process

We know about relation between Process and Thread.

Thread comes under Process, we can say Process is a container and Thread is an element of a container.

But what about Service ?

I can say Process and Thread having same genre.

Can we say the same thing for Services?

I found Window Services and Android Services having similarity, say in Android if we want to play Media then we have to get **getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE)** likewise in Windows (8) if you stop **Windows Audio (audiosrv.dll)** services from **services.msc** then Media will not play.

What is Service?
**Windows**
A service is an application type that runs in the system background without a user     interface and is similar to a UNIX daemon process.

**Android** A service is a component which runs in the background, without direct interaction with the user.

A service runs by default in the same process in the main thread as the application.
Services which run in the process of the application are sometimes called local services.

With above definition we can say apparently that **Service is also a Process** (i am not sure, please make me correct)

Answer (score 1):

Let me start with the statement - ***Service is not a process. It is an activity without GUI***

If you start a thread, it runs parallel with your main activity thread. But a Service is not guaranteed to always run in a new thread. *So, you cannot call a service similar to Thread.*

**A Service is not a separate process.** The Service object itself does not imply it is running in its own process; unless otherwise specified, it runs in the same process as the application it is part of.

**A Service is not a thread**. It is not a means itself to do work off of the main thread (to avoid Application Not Responding errors).

**So When to use of a service in your application ?**

1. If your application tells the system about something it wants to be doing in the background (even when the user is not directly interacting with the application). This corresponds to calls to `Context.startService()`, which ask the system to schedule work for the service, to be run until the service or someone else explicitly stop it.

**Reason -** Your application together with all its global variables will not be wiped out as long as there is a Service still running. So if the user is not interacting with your application and some other application in foreground needs more memory and if the OS triggers a low memory warning and your activity is destroyed, still your application is not completely lost as the service is running.

2. A facility for an application to expose some of its functionality to other applications. This corresponds to calls to `Context.bindService()`, which allows a long-standing connection to be made to the service in order to interact with it.

**How the Application priority is defined based on service ?**

1. If the service is currently executing code in its onCreate(), onStartCommand(), or onDestroy() methods, then the hosting process will be a foreground process to ensure this code can execute without being killed.
2. If the service has been started, then its hosting process is considered to be less important than any processes that are currently visible to the user on-screen, but more important than any process not visible.
3. If there are clients bound to the service, then the service's hosting process is never less important than the most important client.

A started service can use the startForeground(int, Notification) API to put the service in a foreground state, where the system considers it to be something the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for killing when low on memory.